# Объеденить 2 файла в 1 список python

Tags: python

По условию задачи мне нужно открыть 2 файла (с текстом) и объденить их в 1, и уже дальше делать с ним действия. Попробовала много вариантов из инета (учусь только), но не получается почему-то.. выдает ошибку, которую я не понимаю

Вот одна из моих попыток:

```
firstlist = open('words1.txt','r')
secondlist = open('words2.txt','r')

some_string = firstlist + secondlist

some_list = some_string.split()
result = [word for word in some_list if len(word) % 2 != 0]
sorted(result, key=len)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

Буду рада любой помощи/подсказке :)

Comment: какую ошибку-то? firstlist  и secondlist это НЕ текст из файла. Текст из файла вам нужно еще прочитать.

Comment: @Эникейщик аа, поняла. как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

что в голову по быстрому пришло, попробуй, устроит ли тебя результат, а дальше по аналогии прочти 3 файл и делай с ним необходимые действия

```
first = open('words1.txt', 'r')
second = open('words2.txt', 'r')
third = open('words3.txt' , 'w')
for i in first.read().split():
    somestring = i
    third.write(somestring + '\n')
for j in second.read().split():
    somestring = j
    third.write(somestring + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

По простому можно сделать вот так:

```
a = open("первый.txt","r")
a = a.read().split()
b = open("второй.txt","r")
b = b.read().split()
print(a+b)
```

результатом будет:
['1323212312', 'ggggggg']

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [] #пустой список
list.append(open('words1.txt','r').read()) #добавляем данные с первого файла в список
list.append(open('words2.txt','r').read())#добавляем данные с второго файла в список 
print(list) #выводим список
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
read = lambda filename: [x for x in open(filename, 'r', encoding='UTF-8').read().split('\n') if x]
filenames = ('1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt')
result = [y for z in [read(x) for x in filenames] for y in z]
```